# I am using Camera API and QRCode API in my Project, Can i implement multitasking(splitvIew) in my Project

Tags: ios, multitasking, ios9

**I am using Camera API and QRCode API in my Project, Can i implement multitasking(splitvIew, SlideOver) in my Project.**
I think that when we use camera API, want to use fullscreen.
My project also have some other functionalities.
**is it possible to use Fullscreen only when use Camera API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you app is camera-centric app OR Gaming related, Then Apple suggest to opt out above feature.

**Apple Documentation Says**

> Consider opting out only if your app falls into one of these narrow
>   categories:
>
> Camera-centric apps, where using the entire screen for preview and
>   capturing a moment quickly is your primary feature.
>
> Full-device apps,such as games that use iPad sensors as part of their
>   core gameplay Otherwise, Apple, and your customers, expect you to
>   adopt Slide Over and Split View.

To opt out of being eligible to participate in Slide Over and Split View, add the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value `YES`.

Let me know if you need more clarification for the same.

Comment: iOS 9 build in APP FaceTime is working well in splitview feature. Can use faceTime camera and other app at same time.

Comment: Apple said, Consider if your application is using full screen feature. It depends on your app functionality, Split view work based on Auto Layout feature & if you think functionality which you have provided in full screen will work fine in split view then you can keep it enable. I think so.

Comment: @Sabareesh, Why you have rejected the answer after accepting it? Please let me know if you need anymore information for this.